# Is it possible in Java to override 'toString' for an Objects array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, tostring

Is it possible in Java to override a toString for an Objects array?

For example, let's say I created a simple class, `User` (it doesn't really matter which class is it since this is a general question). Is it possible that, once the client creates a `User[]` array and the client uses `System.out.print(array)`, it won't print the array's address but instead a customized `toString()`?

PS: of course I can't just override `toString()` in my class since it's related to single instances.

Comment: Something like `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: Note that `Object[].toString()` does **not** return the "address" of the array. It returns the arrays [identity hash code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Of course you can create a static method User.toString( User[] ), but it won't be called implicitly.

Comment: I dont want to use static methods for printing, im trying to achieve the toString() with no parameters..

Comment: Understood.  That's why the first word of my answer was "no".

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Arrays.toString(Object[] a);` which will call the `toString()` method on each object in the array.

**Edit** (from comment):

I understand what it is you're trying to achieve, but Java doesn't support that at this time.

In Java, arrays are objects that are dynamically created and may be assigned to variables of type Object. All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array. See [JLS Ch10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

When you invoke `toString()` on an object it returns a string that "textually represents" the object. Because an array is an instance of Object that is why you only get the name of the class, the @ and a hex value. See [Object#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

The [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) method returns the equivalent of the array as a list, which is iterated over and `toString()` called on each object in the list.

So while you won't be able to do `System.out.println(userList);` you can do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userList);` which will essentially achieve the same thing.

Comment: I still don't understand how that achieves what i wanted, assuming i have some Class, i want that this class "to support" toString() for an array type. an example: creating Class[] array = new Class[3], once the System.out.println(array) is performed, that Class will have a toString() for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a separate class containing the array, and override `toString()`.

I think the simplest solution is to extend the `ArrayList` class, and just override `toString()` (for example, `UserArrayList`).

Comment: OP isn't using an ArrayList, he is using an array.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can do this is to re-compile `Object.toString()` and add `instanceof` clauses.

I had requested a change in Project Coin to handle arrays in a more object orientated way. I felt that it's too much for beginners to learn all the functionality you need in Array, Arrays and 7 other helper classes which are commonly used.

I think in the end it was concluded that to make arrays properly object orientated is a non-trivial task which will be pushed back to Java 9 or beyond.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
User[] array = new User[2];
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

of course if you have customized `user.toString()` method

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to wrap all calls to `Object.toString` with an [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) around [advice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_%28programming%29) and return the desired output for arrays. However, I don't think it's a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. When you declare an array, then Java in fact creates a hidden object of type Array. It is a special kind of class (for example, it supports the index access [] operator) which normal code cannot directly access.

If you wanted to override toString(), you would have to extend this class. But you cannot do it, since it is hidden.

I think it is good to be it this way. If one could extend the Array class, then one could add all kinds of methods there. And when someone else manages this code, they see custom methods on arrays and they are "WTF... Is this C++ or what?".