# Java println(charArray + String) vs println(charArray)

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, concatenation

I have

```
char c1 = 'S';           // S as a character
char c2 = '\u0068';      // h in Unicode
char c3 = 0x0065;        // e in hexadecimal
char c4 = 0154;          // l in octal
char c5 = (char) 131170; // b, casted (131170-131072=121)
char c6 = (char) 131193; // y, casted (131193-131072=121)
char c7 = '\'';          // ' apostrophe special character
char c8 = 's';           // s as a character
char[] autoDesignerArray = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8};
```

And

```
System.out.println(autoDesignerArray + "Mustang");
```

Output: [C@c17164Mustang

```
System.out.println(autoDesignerArray);
```

Output: Shelby's

I'm not understanding why I get the weird output when I concatenate the char array with a string. What is the "[C@c17164"? The location in memory? And why do I get that when I concatenate with a string, but I get what I would expect when I print it alone?

Comment: `System.out.println(autoDesignerArray + "Mustang");` and `System.out.println(autoDesignerArray);` are not the same method. `System.out.println` provide an overload that handle `char` array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `System.out.println(X + Y)` is equal to the expression
`System.out.println(X.toString() + Y.toString())`.

When you call `System.out.println(autoDesignerArray + "Mustang")`  `autoDesignerArray.toString()` (which is `"[C@c17164"`) is concatenated with  `"Mustang"` and the result is printed.

Comment: According to your 2nd point When you call System.out.println(autoDesignerArray) autoDesignerArray.toString() (which is "[C@c17164") should be printed but  it prints Shelby's. Without String concatenation with array prints actual data but if we concatenate array with String then it prints hashcode address.

Comment: @VikasKumarSingh "*According to your 2nd point When you call System.out.println(autoDesignerArray) autoDesignerArray.toString() (which is "[C@c17164") should be printed*" not quite, `autoDesignerArray.toString()` returns string `"[C@c17164"`, but `println(autoDesignerArray)` doesn't involve `toString()`, it simply prints each character from array. It is possible because in `PrintStream` (which `System.out` is instance of) exist few overloaded `println` methods, and one of them is `println(char[])`.

Answer (score 2):

Since every has array has a class the string you get is the object representation of its object i.e.  `[C@c17164Mustang`  where

- `[C` is a class name (`[` represent 1d array)
- `@` concates the the string
- `c17164` some hash code
- `Mustang` your string

to check the class name of array do `System.out.println(yourArray.getClass().getName());`

For ex if you do `System.out.println(new Object());` you will get something like `java.lang.Object@25154f` the string representation of object created.

And to print the actual values of array do `System.out.println((java.util.Arrays.toString(autoDesignerArray)));` which gives

`[S, h, e, l, b, y, ', s]`

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/jvyRzo)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the other part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays in java don't have overwritten `toString()` method**, which means that:

1. `System.out.println(autoDesignerArray + "Mustang");`

   - will print default `toString()` of array and concatenate it with the string
   - the default implementation of `toString()` will print the binary name followed by `hashCode()` (char array will print [C followed by it's hash code)
2. `System.out.println(autoDesignerArray);`

   - will actually call Arrays.toString() or similar functionality handling the `toString()` of arrays correctly

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the 2nd point is due to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-). Also not sure about the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with Arrays and why the fact that they don't implicitly inherit `Object` - For more information feel free to check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504925/why-are-arrays-objects-but-can-not-be-used-as-a-base-class/27505121#27505121) (have an answer there).

`println(char[] s)` does somewhat confuse me in the [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char[])) - In C you would generally iterate through every element within the array and `print` each element follow by a `\n` to break the line.

However the jist of it all is that `autoDesignerArray.toString()` won't really work as you wish it would (Which is why it returns `[C@c17164`).