# How to log the values of an array in camel body within the route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have pasted the part of the code below, where i am trying to log the array in camel body

```
...
    .convertBodyTo(UserInfo[].class)
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,logger,"Output- ${body}")
```

But in the log

```
- Output-  (UerInfo[])- [Lcom.bhge.entitlement.service.dto.UserInfo;@1e37cb10
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use camel bean

Create a method somewhere in your java code to control the display and use [camel bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) link to the method.

---

The log part in your code is calling `UerInfo[].toString()` which return [identity hash code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-). Base on this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295705/3759505), you are unable to override `UerInfo[].toString()` to achieve your goal by existing code.